# What is the source of the hadith that the Prophet ﷺ shall be an opponent to one who harms non-muslim citizens?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, non-muslim, treaty

Prophet Muhammad (pbuh) said:
“Whoever harms a non-Muslim citizen, I will be his enemy on the Day of Resurrection.”

I just want to ask what is the source of this hadith Bukhari , muslim or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest hadith to this wording IMO is:

> من آذى ذميا فأنا خصمه، ومن كنت خصمه خصمته يوم القيامة
>
> Whoever hurts a Dhimmi, I shall be his opponent, and whosoever I oppose will be defeated on the Day of Judgement. (paraphrased)
>
> <sup>— [Taareekh Baghdaad](https://shamela.ws/index.php/book/736/5064)</sup>

This is **not** from Bukhari or Muslim, and it is weak and has been classed as [fabricated](https://shamela.ws/book/882/657) as well. However the main lesson it conveys is correct: that it is not permissible to harm a Dhimmi (obviously except by legal rights). Corroboration of this may be found in authentic ahadith:

> من قتل معاهدا لم يرح رائحة الجنة، وإن ريحها توجد من مسيرة أربعين عاما
>
> Whoever killed a person having a treaty with the Muslims, shall not smell the smell of Paradise though its smell is perceived from a distance of forty years.
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3166)</sup>

> ألا من ظلم معاهدا أو انتقصه أو كلفه فوق طاقته أو أخذ منه شيئا بغير طيب نفس فأنا حجيجه يوم القيامة
>
> If anyone wrongs a Mu'ahid, detracts from his rights, burdens him with
> more work than he is able to do, or takes something from him without
> his consent, I will plead for him (the Mu'ahid) on the Day of
> Resurrection.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3052)</sup>

**Ref:** [Maqaasid al-Hasanah](https://shamela.ws/book/23177/590), [islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/51557/).

---

**Definitions:**

A Dhimmi is a non-muslim who agrees to pay Jizya and be under Islamic rule.

A Mu'ahid is a non-muslim who has a peace treaty with the Muslims. And in ahadith it is often used to refer to the Dhimmis. From Lisan al-‘Arab: المعاهد: من كان بينك وبينه عهد، وأكثر ما يطلق في الحديث على أهل الذمة

Comment: What is mu'ahid?

Comment: @Anonymous Updated answer to cover that.